# Android create a Word (doc) file

Tags: android, ms-word

I have a program, on a web server, that creates a .doc file from a user input of a form. A the user clicks Submit it immediately aske the user to View or Save. It written in asp.net (VB.net) and it works really well. I have an Android app that I am trying to access that form and do the same thing. When I access the form and click Submit it saves the form page as an HTML in the cell phone's Document section.

Is there a way to create the Word file from user form either from the web server or I can rewrite it to do it from inside the mobile app?

thanks

Comment: just create the file using .doc format.. then check it

Answer (score 0):

As you said that the form is in VB.Net(ASP.Net) therefore your question is typically related to MS .Net technology and not Android. You better have to use the [Word Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee836186%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are in Java-land, then you could use [**Apache POI**](http://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: RDC & Jason Clown - Apache POI does not work on Android, some  dependencies dont build.

Answer (score -1):

you should try Apache [POI library .](http://poi.apache.org/)
This library supports to read, write and get the properties of all Microsoft Office Documents like doc ,ppt and xls files.
Here is an example how use it . Hope it helps.